# Cannot Convert the expressions type from type 'ST2" to type '(String!)?'

Tags: ios, closures, swift

While there are a bunch of Cannot Convert question in Swift I still cannot resolve this. I have simplified it down.

Given a method

```
func myMethod(s: String,
    completion:((String!)?))
{
    let myString : String!   = ""
    completion(myString)
}
```

No matter what I put into the completion block I get a compiler error.
for example
Cannot Convert the expression's type 'ST2' to type (String!)?

I was trying to rewrite an Obj C function in Swift.

Please explain what this ST(n) notation means, and how to avoid these errors.

### edit

For the sake of completeness this is the actual method I was trying to rewrite in Swift from OBJ-C

```
+ (void)insertFileWithService:(GTLServiceDrive *)service
                        title:(NSString *)title
                  description:(NSString *)description
                     parentId:(NSString *)parentId
                     mimeType:(NSString *)mimeType
                         data:(NSData *)data
              completionBlock:(void (^)(GTLDriveFile *, NSError *))completionBlock {
  GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];


  GTLQueryDrive *query =
    [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesInsertWithObject:file
                                uploadParameters:uploadParameters];


  GTLServiceTicket *queryTicket =
    [service executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                            GTLDriveFile *insertedFile, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil) {
          // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
          // NSLog(@"File ID: %@", insertedFile.identifier);
          completionBlock(insertedFile, nil);
        } else {
          NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
          completionBlock(nil, error);
        }
      }];
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using `(String!)?`‽

Comment: It is a common practice if you look at some of the predefined methods. It is not relevant either changing it to String without the ? and/or ! does not help

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here, especially within the completion argument.Completion is just another self-chosen argument name, it isn't anything unique. And String! force unwraps an optional String, I might just not have read far enough but that ((String!)?) line looks unusual. If you are trying to pass a function in should look more like **completion: String -> Bool** citing the required input and the output of the function to be passed

Comment: Which predefined methods use it? It is definitely relevant: the type (and especially optionals) dictates how you use the variable in code.

Comment: An example of a GTL function using this service.executeQuery(query: GTLQueryProtocol?, completionHandler: ((GTLServiceTicket!, AnyObject!, NSError!) -> Void)?)

Comment: Okay, so completionHandler is either nil, or a function that takes `(GTLServiceTicket!,AnyObject!,NSError!)` and returns nothing. How does that relate to `(String!)?`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your method as:

```
func myMethod(s: String, completion:((String!) -> ())?)
```

This should declare myMethod's second parameter as an optional block that takes an explicitly unwrapped String and returns Void (equivalent to an empty tuple, `()`, in Swift), which I think is what you're looking for, yes?

Comment: I Think this is the correct answer in my case - completion:((GTLDriveFile!)?,(NSError!)?) -> ())

Comment: Do you know what the ST(n) notation means ? Which I was getting in my error messages

Comment: I'm afraid not—I'm guessing it's some compiler internal, but I can't guess at what the compiler was guessing at. All you were missing was the return type of the closure, so I suppose the compiler was interpreting it as some other type.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd convert your actual method:

```
func insertFile(
    service:GTLServiceDrive,
    title:NSString,
    description:NSString,
    parentId:NSString,
    mimeType:NSString,
    data:NSData,
    completionBlock:(GTLDriveFile?, NSError?) -> () {
    // ...
}
```

And this is how to call it:

```
insertFile(
    service:/* ... */,
    title:/* ... */,
    description:/* ... */,
    parentId:/* ... */,
    mimeType:/* ... */,
    data:/* ... */,
    completionBlock: { (file:GTLDriveFile?, error:NSError?) -> () in    
        // ... completion    
})
```